# Link directly to tab from anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to directly linking from anchor link like Go back to 3 tab  And i can't make it working. It's working perfectly from the menu but when i am trying to linking from the tab5 to tab3 is not working with anchor.

Here is the JS i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">




jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();



        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });





});

</script>
```

Is something wrong on my code or missing?

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i correctly understood you want to change tab programmatically, if so you can use `$('.tabs').tabs('option', 'active', tab_index);`, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function() {
    $('.tabs').tabs();

    $("#go_to_tab_3").click(function() {
        $('.tabs').tabs('option', 'active', 2); //index 2 mean tab 3
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>tab 1 content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>tab 2 content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>tab 3 content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button id='go_to_tab_3' type='button'>Go to tab 3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can i add this on my current code without destroying it?Because i have already tried a lot of code found on web and here on stack overflow and destroyed also the navigation.Thanks

Comment: I tried the code ..is working..but the li element of the tab is not shown as selected

Comment: You're welcome, okay update your OP and i'll check it.